# Creating a buffer in python to store data before sending it out

Tags: python, buffer, storage

I receive an mp3 stream in client1 and then I send it out again to client2 in real time.
I want to create a buffer which would store some data and it would only send it out to client2 when it fills completely. This would help me to avoid deadlocks.

I am not sure how to create such a buffer in python. What data structure can I use and how can I implement it? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I consider idiomatic and pythonic is using a `list` and `.append()` each buffer element/string to the list. When I'm done and I want the whole buffer, I do `"".join(buffer_list)` and get the whole shebang. It works like a StringBuilder

You could also look into `StringIO` and the C-extended version.

This page has a lot of info on the subject: [Efficient String Concatenation in Python](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/)